# Lost my Pixelize settings in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, filter

I'm on Windows 10, and just an hour ago, I did a Filters/Blur/Pixelize... on a PNG image succesfully; at that time, I did get this dialog for the Pixelize filter options - taken from https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-filter-pixelize.html :

[image: usual pixelize options]

However, now I started Gimp again, and did a Filters/Blur/Pixelize... on a different PNG image - but the dialog I get is this instead:

[image: pixelize options weird]

Obviously, this does not really do the Pixelize effect (I'm not sure why it says GEGL operation) - and I cannot really tell how to stop it either.

What the hell is going on, and how do I get Pixelize to work again?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, apparently, the Pixelize settings window ended up somewhere in the background, behind other windows - finally I got it again, this is how it should look like:

[image: pixelize back again]

So you still get GEGL operation written in the left part of the GIMP window, and the Pixelize settings is in a separate window - I had just remembered wrong, and thought Pixelize settings was otherwise in the left part of the GIMP window.